# How do I fix my Xbox 360 disk read error

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

My Xbox is an old fat white 60GB model from 2007. In the last two months I got the 'open tray' disk read error. Sometimes the disk will be recognised and even play but this is only maybe 10% of the time and has not happened in a while. I have taken a few steps to fix this issue.

Step1: Open the Xbox and clean the fans and mother board. 
Result, same error

Step2: Open the disk drive, clean all the dust out and polish the lazer with rubbing solution.
Result, Same Error

Step 3: Push the lazer back on its runners by hand to reset it.
Result, Same Error.

The systerm has never had a RROD, ecept duing a power cut over 3 years ago. And this drive error is very new. 
What can i do now? 
Can I reset the drive some how?
Can I install a new drive?
Is their any further cleaning to do?

Please Help, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install a new CD drive yourself, so long as you find a compatible model.

Having never installed one of these on Xbox myself, I can't guarantee it'll work 100%, but here's a [list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_specifications#List_of_DVD_drives) of drives in the Xbox 360 models, if you get one of these you are probably in the clear.

There's a video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Sk3TosB1mE) on how to replace the DVD drive, however it does note that you need to know how to solder to do it, so if you don't want to mess with it, then you might want to just get a used xbox 360 on amazon. Get the 4GB one since you can transfer the hard drive over using a little hard drive caddy you can get for pretty cheap.

Comment: Pretty sure Xbox 360 disk trays are registered to the Xboxresulting in it being only a DVD player if you install a different drive without flashing the new drive information to the rom. Although I don't think Micrsoft would agree.